# How does the kimonify bookmarklet work with restrictive pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, iframe

I am curious how the kimonify bookmarklet works. My hope was to add a simple javascript bookmarklet that could be run to add jquery to an existing page and let me do some element selections/modifications to the page. I notice that Kimonify somehow reloads the page and after trying several methods (all of which seem to lack the facebook.com compatibility that kimonify has) I'm stumped.

So far I tried
1. Loading facebook.com into an iframe, which doesn't work because they disallow this
2. Loading jquery.js with a bookmarklet and then running element selection on the page (using createElement of type script), which doesn't work because they only allow script loading from certain whitelisted domains

I'm a JS novice who is stumped because kimonify just works (although it throws a message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.kimonolabs.com' is therefore not allowed access. )

I've gleaned the following, kimonify bookmarklet redirects to the http://www.kimonolabs.com/load page, where it seems like they are creating an iframe and possibly grabbing the content (jsonp?) and then reassembling it via jquery.

Can anyone clarify how this magic happens?